# How to easily traverse a deserialized Xml document?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization

I am currently trying to make an importer for collada(.dae) files, which are based on XML. I have the xml file deserialized into objects that I can easily access.
For example, the .dae file may have a setup like this...

```
<library_geometries>
<geometry id="Cube1s_008-mesh" name="Cube1s.008">
  <mesh>
    <source id="Cube1s_008-mesh-positions">
       <float_array ...... />
    </source>
    <source id="Cube1s_008-mesh-normals">
    </source>
    <vertices id="Cube1s_008-mesh-vertices">
      <input semantic="POSITION" source="#Cube1s_008-mesh-positions"/>
    </vertices>
  </mesh>
</geometry>
<geometry>
 ....
</geometry>
</library_geometries>
```

It is then deserialized (with xmlSerializer.Deserialize) in a similar fashion. So to access the second "source" in "mesh" I would do library_geometries.geometry[0].mesh.source[1];

All is good there, the problem I am running into is easily traversing this deserialized xml document.

For example, in "vertices" there is a source="#Cube1s_008-mesh-positions" which basically means "to access the vertices data, go to the source with an id of "Cube1s_008-mesh-positions"". What I want to do is to easily go from the vertices directly to the source, or anything, that has that id.
So it would look something like library_geometries.geometry[0].mesh.vertices.GoToSource(); and with that I can do library_geometries.geometry[0].mesh.vertices.GoToSource().float_array.values;

I am assuming I would need to do this with reflection.
Perhaps search for any field that has [XmlAttribute("id")] and then somehow return its object in its proper type.
Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic methods you can use.

```css
1) Build a dictionary
2) Add a new property Geometry geometry to the class veritices which is NonSerialize.  After deserialize, enumerate through the classes adding the value to the property geometry.
```

Comment: Your 2nd method is similar to what I have been doing. I add a variable to the vertices class called "sourceElement" which can lead me directly to the source element this vertex is pointing to. To set it up, I have to do reflection, get all the sources, find the source the vertex points to and assign it to the sourceElement variable. The problem is, I would need to do this for every type of element with an ID attribute. I then started trying to just get anything that has an ID attribute and storing it, but when it is stored, it is an object and not stored as the correct type, making it unusable

Answer (score 0):

That is why I like dictionaries.  I often use classes like the one below for nested structures.

```css
public class Node
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<Node> children { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> dict { get; set; }
}
```